# How to print float numbers with awk

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, bc

I have this input file:

```
Adrian 20.6
Bruce 40.2
Adrian 30.4
Janick 24.2
Dave 42.7
Bruce 42.9
Janick 41.2
```

And with a answer I've got here, I was able to sum the numbers, but now the numbers are float and I don't know how to print them.

For now, my output is:

```
Adrian 50
Bruce 82
Dave 42
Janick 65
```

But it should be with the decimals as well.

```
$(awk '{sum[$1] += $2} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]}' $arq > temp.txt && sort temp.txt)
```

I've made that code to sort by alphabetical order.

Comment: With `printf` just like C (without the `(..)`). See [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) Why are you calling `awk` within a *Command Substitution*, e.g. `$(awk ... )` -- that would tend to show you are calling `awk` on a per-iteration basis.  That is generally the least efficient way to use any shell utility. Sometimes needed, but often not. That can work to initialize an array, but there isn't enough information provided to tell.

Comment: Because it's inside a script. And I've tried with printf, but it didn't work. Or I don't know where to insert the printf.

Comment: `awk` handles floating-point values fine. Your summation of `sum[$1] += $2` will produce a floating point number. Simply using `awk '{sum[$1] += $2} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]}' file` produces, e.g. `Bruce 83.1` and `Dave 42.7`, ... Adding `| sort` outputs the results in sorted order. Adding `| sort > temp.txt` redirects the sorted output with floating point numbers to `temp.txt`, no *Command Substitution* needed (you may be closer than you think `:)`

Comment: I've tried removing the sort, and the command substitution. It didn't work as well. Don't know what's happening, but still trying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in a locale where the decimal separator is not `.` so the `.` is being treated as any other character that's not part of a number (e.g. `a` or `@`) and so your numbers are being truncated to the part before the `.`.

Do `LC_ALL=C awk '...'` to set your locale to one that does use a `.` for the decimal separator and then your script will work as-is.

Comment: Well played Ed. Thinking one step ahead -- again...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are closer than you think, but your problems stem from not handling putting the pieces together in the right order. By default `awk` handles floating-point math. Your summation of `sum[$1] += $2` will be done with floating point numbers if your input numbers contains decimal places.

Why you are using a *Command Substitution*, e.g. `$(..)` is unclear. That isn't needed to fill `temp.txt` with the sorted sums from your input. Let's take for example your input file in a file named `input`. Then to sum and output the values you need nothing more than:

```
awk '{sum[$1] += $2} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]}' input
```

Which results in the output of:

```
Bruce 83.1
Dave 42.7
Adrian 51
Janick 65.4
```

To sort the results, simply pipe the `awk` output to `sort`, e.g.

```
awk '{sum[$1] += $2} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]}' input | sort
```

Result:

```
Adrian 51
Bruce 83.1
Dave 42.7
Janick 65.4
```

Now, to fill `temp.txt`, you simply need to redirect the output to `temp.txt`, e.g.

```
awk '{sum[$1] += $2} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]}' input | sort > temp.txt
```

`temp.txt` now contains the sorted output. To nicely tabularize the output, you can format the output by saving the max length for `$1` and setting the name field-width to `max` and then outputting the floating-point number in a fixed format (total floating-point field-width `10` with `1` digit following the decimal point), e.g.

```
{sum[$1] += $2; len=length($1); if(len>max)max=len} ...  printf "%-*s%10.1f\n", max, i, sum[i]
```

Or in full-form:

```
awk '{sum[$1] += $2; len=length($1); if(len>max)max=len} END {for (i in sum) printf "%-*s%10.1f\n", max, i, sum[i]}' input | sort > temp.txt
```

With the results in `temp.txt` now being:

```
$ cat temp.txt
Adrian      51.0
Bruce       83.1
Dave        42.7
Janick      65.4
```

Comment: Please have the integrity to explain your downvote.